# Bootstrap: dropdown doesnt work after using ajax modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

This is how I open up an ajax modal:

```
    // MODAL AJAX   
$('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function() {
    $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
});     

$('.remote-click').click(function(){
    var dataContent = $(this).attr("data-content");
    $('.spinner').show();

    setTimeout(function(){
    $('#remote').modal({remote: 'ajax.php?' + dataContent, backdrop: 'static', show: true});
    }, 1000);   
    setTimeout(function(){
    $('.spinner').hide();
    }, 2000);           

});
```

After opening a modal this way the bootstrap dropdown function on the site doesnt work. It only works if I refresh the whole page.

Also I have the problem that you'll see the old ajax modal content for some seconds using this code, before the new one loads. But the loading indicator will be shown first. I couldn't figure out how to solve this.

Appreciate any suggestions on both issues!

Comment: Check your browser console if it prints any errors.

Comment: It doesn't print any errors